# jquery $.get() returns undefined when the function us run

Tags: jquery, csv

Lets says:
f is equal to /path/to/file.csv
l is equal to the div ID
t is equal to the option to return results or update the div

```
function CsvCount(f,l,t) {
    $.get(f, function(data) {
        var lineCount = data.split('\n').length;
        if( t == 'print' ) {
            $(l).text(lineCount);
        } else {
            return lineCount;
        }
});
```

this return undefined :(

Could anyone help me?

Just of this function to work :)